# One time binding for angular translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using [Angular translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) for my development. I wonder if there is a global configuration for having one time binding for the translation.

Something I expect

```
$translateProvider.enableOneTimeBinding(true);
```

Comment: A global function to enableOneTimeBinding for translations would be pretty awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend looking at ajwhite's "Angular Translate Once" directive. It's an extension to Angular Translate that adds support for one time bindings.

You can read about it here: [Atticus White on Angular Translate Once](https://atticuswhite.com/blog/angularjs-translate-once-angular-translate-one-time-binding/) or you can take a look at [Angular Translate Once's Github Repo](https://github.com/ajwhite/angular-translate-once)

Comment: My concern is that would that be compatible with upcoming newer version of angular translate?

Comment: It currently requires Angular Translate 2.6.1. I'm unsure what the developer's plans are for newer and upcoming versions of Angular Translate. If you're app will utilize features added to an upcoming version, it might be worthwhile to open an issue asking about future version support.

Comment: Great question stackdisplay and suggestion @AlexJohnson. I would certainly like to keep things compatible with future Angular Translate versions. There's a decent amount of people using it, so I would like to make sure the project continues to provide support.